# Exception raised using HTML code in JSON string

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to use HTML code in a JSON string but I've some problems.
The JSON.parse(string) raise the exception `"Unexpected token <"`.

Looking for a solution on internet I saw that the problem shouldn't exists. So I tried with a validator ( http://jsonlint.com/ ) and the response is

```
Parse error on line 1580:
...re",        "DEU": "<b>BESCHREIBUNG</b>
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Ok, the problem is the lt symbol...wait! The error is on line 1580 but I've more lt/gt symbols before that, for example:

```
...
[1557] "VAC_SAFETY_LONG": {
[1558]     "ITA": "Segnale sicurezza vuoto mancante",
[1559]     "ENG": "Vacuum safety signal missing",
[1560]     "DEU": "<b>BESCHREIBUNG</b><br> Dieser Alarm wird ausgelost, wenn die Sicherheitsbedingungen fur den Aufbau des Vakuums im Gehause nicht gegeben sind. <br><br><b>REAKTION DES OFENS</b><br> Keine spezifische Reaktion. <br><br><b>URSACHEN UND ABHILFE</b><br> Der Gehausedruck ist hoher als der Atmospharendruck. <br><br> Problem mit dem Niederdruckschalter [BSP_LP]. <br><br> Den Druckschalter uberprufen."
[1561] },
...
[1572] "VOP_LONG": {
[1573]     "ITA": "Sovrapressione campana",
[1574]     "ENG": "Vessel overpressure",
[1575]     "DEU": "<b>BESCHREIBUNG</b><br> Dieser Alarm wird ausgelost, wenn der im Gehause vorliegende Druck den zulassigen Hochstwert ubersteigt. <br><br><b>REAKTION DES OFENS</b><br> Das Gaseinlassventil schlieBt sich. Sollte sich das Gaseinlassventil nicht schnell genug schlieBen, offnet sich das Sicherheitsventil. <br><br><b>URSACHEN UND ABHILFE</b><br> Ungenaue Druckmessung. Der Druckmesser sollte neu justiert oder ersetzt werden. <br><br> Gaseinlassventil zu langsam. Das Elektroventil muss reguliert werden, damit sich das Ventil rascher schlieBt."
[1576] },
[1577] "VOT_LONG": {
[1578]     "ITA": "Sovratemperatura campana",
[1579]     "ENG": "Vessel overtemperature",
[1580]     "DEU": "<b>BESCHREIBUNG</b><br> Dieser Alarm wird ausgelost, wenn die Gehausetemperatur hoher als die maximal zulassige Temperatur fur den Ofen ist.  <br><br><b>REAKTION DES OFENS</b><br> Die Aufheizung wird angehalten und der Ofen verharrt im Wartezustand. <br><br><b>URSACHEN UND ABHILFE</b><br> Mangel an Kuhlwasser fur das Gehause oder zu hohe Wassertemperatur. In diesem Fall muss das Kuhlwassersystem kontrolliert werden. <br><br> Aus irgendeinem Grund liefert die Heizkammer keine gute Isolierung. Die Hitzeschilde schlieBen unter Umstanden nicht richtig oder einige Teile der Kammerwand konnen beschadigt sein. Der Ofen muss sich abkuhlen und die Heizkammer inspiziert werden. <br><br> Funktionsstorung eines Temperaturschalters. Wenn sich keine Ursache fur den Alarm finden lasst, kann der Temperaturschalter, der den Alarm ausgelost hat, durch einen anderen Schalter aus dem Ersatzteilbestand ausgetauscht werden und ein neuer Zyklus gestartet werden."
[1581] },
...
```

The strings indexed by "DEU" start with the same chars, so why one raises the error and the others not?

Comment: Can you provide the whole file somewhere? If you put lines 1577-1580 within an object, it validates fine.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M1JVL1Wb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly in line 1580 of your JSON, but not in the HTML tags. It's a tab character, right here before the double `<br>` tag (I don't think it will be rendered as a tab here anyway):

```
"DEU": "<b>BESCHREIBUNG</b><br> ... fur den Ofen ist.    <br><br>
```

Apparently, it's not in your question, but is present in the Pastebin code. If you remove it, JSONLint will parse it correctly.